# Bad Request (#400) Parámetros requeridos ausentes:yii2

Tags: yii2

estoy tratando de enviar desde una imagen un id, y mandarlo a una vista y filtrar un crud en la vista que indico a continuación

controller

```
   namespace app\controllers;

   use Yii;
   use app\models\Issues;
   use app\models\IssuesSearch;
   use yii\web\Controller;
   use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
   use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

   /**
   * IssuesController implements the CRUD actions for Issues model.
   */
 class IssuesController extends Controller
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Lists all Issues models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new IssuesSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Displays a single Issues model.
 * @param integer $idissues
 * @param integer $project_idproject
 * @return mixed
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
public function actionView($idissues, $project_idproject)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($idissues, $project_idproject),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Creates a new Issues model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Issues();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'idissues' => $model->idissues, 'project_idproject' => $model->project_idproject]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Updates an existing Issues model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $idissues
 * @param integer $project_idproject
 * @return mixed
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
public function actionUpdate($idissues, $project_idproject)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($idissues, $project_idproject);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'idissues' => $model->idissues, 'project_idproject' => $model->project_idproject]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Deletes an existing Issues model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
 * @param integer $idissues
 * @param integer $project_idproject
 * @return mixed
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
public function actionDelete($idissues, $project_idproject)
{
    $this->findModel($idissues, $project_idproject)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
 public function actionResumen($idissues)
{


    return $this->render('resumen', [
        'model' => $this->findModelresumen($idissues),
    ]);
    // $model= new client;
    // return $this->render('resumen', [
    //     'model' => $this->findModel($idClient),
    // ]);
}


/**
 * Finds the Issues model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param integer $idissues
 * @param integer $project_idproject
 * @return Issues the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
protected function findModel($idissues, $project_idproject)
{
    if (($model = Issues::findOne(['idissues' => $idissues, 'project_idproject' => $project_idproject])) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
protected function findModelresumen($idissues)
{

    if (($model = Issues::findOne(['idissues' => $idissues])) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist. 
  buuu');
}
  }
```

view desde donde envio.

```
 <?php echo Html::a( Html::img('/basic/uploads/'.$url['image'], ['alt' => 
 $url['name'],"width"=>"200", "height"=>"200"]),['resumen', 'id' => 
 $url['idClient']])?>
```

PD: la vista resumen esta en el mismo dir que la el index desde donde envio la peticion.

quiero poder tomar ese id para luego realizar un filtro en un modelo y mostrar una un crud. disculpen si el codigo es un poco enrredado estoy aprendiendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás mandando `id` como parametro y en tu controlador lo tienes como `$idissues`

Tendrías que enviarlo como `['resumen', 'idissues' =>  $url['idClient']])`

o cambiar el nombre de la variable en el action de tu controlador a `$id`

Comment: gracias amigo! solucione

Comment: como puedo dar como culminada la pregunta?

Comment: puedes revisar la página de como aceptar una respuesta
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer